# Frame object during position lerp

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, 3d, orthographic

I've got a camera which is moving to an end position. For the entire duration of the movement, I want to frame an object so the motion looks appealing to the player. The framing of the object does not necessarily stay the same throughout the entire motion ( I want to be able to lerp the viewport position of the object during the lerp )

- I have the starting position and rotation of the camera
- I have the start viewport position of the object relative to the camera
- I have the end viewport position of the object relative to the camera
- my camera is orthographic, so I don't have to worry about frustrum sizes / field of views
- Just a direct lerp between start and an end rotation is not a good solution, as it loses the framing that I'm looking for (tried)

For each update in my lerp:

[1] - I tween between the start and end position of the camera.

[2] - I tween a viewport position that I want to use between start and end viewport position

[3] - I need to calculate the new rotation required to keep the object in my new viewport position calculated in [2]

[4] - I update the rotation and continue the lerp

However, I'm a bit stumped with the calculation in 3 :( I've tried a few variations to try and calculate this, but I can't seem to find a good solution. Does anyone know how to calculate this? Am I approaching this from the correct angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you.

[image]

both angles are equal... if you can calculate the world coordinates of the moving object (based on the view port coordinates) you can also can calculate the world coordinates of the target.

Answer (score 0):

The Quaternion.LookRotation() method should be enought:

```
    public GameObject TargetObject;
    public GameObject CameraObject;

    void Update () {
        CameraObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(TargetObject.transform.position- CameraObject.transform.position );

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sadly that doesn't solve my issue entirely :(.

The problem with that is, it doesn't ensure that the object i'm trying to focus always stays in the viewport location as where I'm expecting it.

Small example is, if my object starts at the right side of my viewport, and I want it to end at the left side of my viewport, regardless of where my position is, it should interpolate between these 2 points on the screen.

Comment: If you got the viewport position where you want your object (A) you only need to know where would be a target (B) which your camera would be looking at. An hipotetic target just in front of your camera. I think You need to know where is  that target(B) for every Update().

Comment: Knowing that the viewport coordinates ranging from (0,0, z)
 in the lower left corner,
 and the coordinates (1,1, z) are the opposite corner.
 The center corresponds to the viewport coordinates (0'5,0'5, z).

Comment: You can calculate the world coordinates of that target with 
Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(0.5,0.5,1)

Comment: Now those target(B) must be rotated like you want
 rotate your object(A) but in the oposite direction and make the camera follows it. 
Creating the effect of that is your object (B) the one that moves.

Comment: The movement of the target (B) begins in viewport (0.5,0.5,1) and ends at a point that must be calculated with the end position of your object (A)

Comment: The angle between the beginning of the end of the object object to the camera is the same angle between the beginning and end of the target (B). You can calculate this angle with Vector3.Angle ().

Comment: Now you can rotate the target (b)with the Quaternion.AngleAxis() method , or directly rotate the camera.

Comment: This is actually what I started thinking of doing as well, and the rotation part isn't really the issue, but rather, What direction should the camera be facing when finding the Viewport position.

Comment: I get a start Viewport position, and an end viewport position.
I move my camera X-units. Now I get a lerped value between my start and end value for my viewport. the problem with that is, I need to be facing something first when I can use that lerped value to get the correct Viewport to world position point. This is where I'm struggling.

what I need is:
Move the camera X units to new position
Calculate the Lerp Viewport position
Rotate the camera so that The target point is in viewport position (note: I can't move the end point, Basically it's a point in a level, so i cant move a chunk)

Comment: What in my mind makes sense is: I need to somehow find out what 1 unit in the viewspace correlates to when pointing the camera directly at my focus point, and then rotate it with X-units so the object is now in the correct location of my viewport. How to do the calculation however I'm kind of lost with..

Comment: Im not sure that what are your trying.... but I think that your camera should look at an emptyObject that moves in oposite direction that the effect you want to create. If you want the effect of an object moving from Viewport(2,0,z) to (-2,0,z), then the target which is looking your camera must move to a point from viexport(0,0,z) to a point you must calculate with the angle that form Viewport(2,0,z) - Viewport(0,0,0) and Viewport(-2,0,z)